# How to stop a $digest loop apparently caused by a filter

Tags: angularjs

Consider the following Plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/10Rs92cRulf9VtI3Bav6

It appears to work correctly, but if you look at the console, you can see that something is wrong.  With just that little table, Angular has already hit the Digest loop limit of 10!

it isn't a problem in a small dataset like this one, but the actual production page has 10 different filters and can span 30+ days.  As the data grows, the $digest looping is getting way, way out of hand.

What can I do to stop it?  I have been pouring over the source code trying to figure out why the Table keeps getting digested over and over and over again, even though the data isn't changing at all.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filters are really for massaging data for the view.

The filter on your ng-repeat that loops and creates the date range is causing the issue. ng-repeat is calling that filter every. time. it. 'repeats' :) and from what I can gather you only need to create the range once at start-up (or when data changes). If you move the date range creation code out of a filter it should be more performant. You might even consider moving the range creation server side.

Forked your plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/XTn7hjbQgV1DxcBlOYVJ.

Comment: Holy Smokes, that was it!  I implemented that fix, and the production code is orders of magnitude faster now.